# Datastage Job aborts Mail notification issue

Tags: datastage

Am working on Datastage 11.5, I have created a sequence jobs with Notification activity but I gave the trigger as Notify when FAILED.

As of now, I am receiving mails when job fails. I need to send mail even when JOB aborts as well. Currently, its not working. what to do ?

Answer (score 0):

I use Version 10 but for fails use the "Exception Handler"-Stage in combination with the "Notification Activity"-Stage. For the aborts trigger your jobs to "warnings" in combination with the "Sequenzer"-Stage and the "Notification Activity"-Stage.

image:https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHRaF.jpg